# textview not align center below of imageview

Tags: android

textview not properly align below imageview in listview see screen shot

[image]

is show center below some image, another image show below right i want to show text  center below of each image

```
    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title2);
    holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image2);

                androidAQuery.id(holder.imgThumb).
              image(fifthscreen.Category_image.get(position), false, false);

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set android:layout_gravity="center"  in textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*you are using* `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` *which will consume maximum width* as `Length` of text of your `TextView`,

*Due to this*  `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` *has no effect*

*Make*  `android:layout_width="90dp"` of `TextView` *equals to your* `ImageView`

Use this

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/title2"
android:layout_width="90dp" <!-- Same width as your ImageView has -->
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all give TextView width 90dp, because you have given it to ImageView, so make TextView as per ImageView size. Then set android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal".

Answer (score 0):

Set the `TextView` width `90dp` instead of `Wrap_content`, same as the `ImageView`,and layout_gravity to  `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`.

**Best wishes**